# Google Maps JS API v2 - jQuery number to word translation thingy

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, javascript

Ive got a problem, Im using jquery for my googlemaps thingy Im doin and Im gettin a number from an php array and I´m reading from it via a for-loop and want to translate that number into a word, for example I get the number 1 in the array and then I´d like to translate that number to the word "Core-router".

And return that word into my marker variable to display that word when I click on the marker on the map.

Here is my code Ive written so far:

```
    <?php echo $location; ?> // where i get the array from...

    var i, myLatLng;
    for (i = 0; i < switches.length; i++) {

        myLatLng = new GLatLng(switches[i][1], switches[i][2]);
          var marker = createTabbedMarker(myLatLng, ["Namn: "+switches[i][0]+ "<br /> Adress: "+switches[i][3]+ "<br /> Type: "+switches[i][4], "N/A","N/A"],["Information","Detaljer","Övrigt"]);
       map.addOverlay(marker, markerOptions);

    }
```

The code is working like a charm and as you can see on the arrayposition 4 switches[i][4]
is where I get the number from, Id like to return a word instead on that position.

The thing I thought about was to do it like this:

Write this in the forloop:

var type = switches[i][4];

```
        if(type == "2") {
            return("Distributionsswitch");
            }
        if(type == "3") {
            return("Accessswitch");
        }
        if(type == "1") {
            return("Core / Edge - router");
            }
```

And somehow return that output to where I now have the :

```
Type: "+switches[i][4],
```

Hope you guys understand what Im looking for, my head is just spinnin right now because of all stress...

Best Regards,

EIGHTYFO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use a function as so

```
function getStringValue(intVal)
    {
        switch(intVal)
        {
            case 1:
            return 'Core / Edge - router';
          case 2:
            return 'Distributionsswitch';
          case 3:
            return 'Accessswitch';
          default:
            return 'UNKNOWN'
        }
    }
```

you can then use

```
var marker = createTabbedMarker(myLatLng, ["Namn: "+switches[i][0]+ "<br /> Adress: "+switches[i][3]+ "<br /> Type: "+getStringValue(switches[i][4]), "N/A","N/A"],["Information","Detaljer","Övrigt"]);
```

I haven't been able to test this so if you have any probs let me know!

HTH 
OneSHOT

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Type: ['', 'Core / Edge - router', 'Distributionsswitch', 'Accessswitch'][switches[i][4]],
```

Just use the number as the index into an array of strings.